# Releasing React Native .apk for demo usage

Tags: android, react-native

I followed steps from this [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android):

Exported .apk can install on all my devices, but when I uninstalled and then installed my phone said 'App not installed'. My clients had the same problem even from the first installation.

There are no multiple users on my phone or any other so I can't do 'uninstall for all users'.

After that I tried to export from Android Studio with same keystore and passwords and it just created more problems with the same initial problem and that's 'App not installed'.

After that I resolved many problems that Android Studio made with updates and I still can't export it properly from Visual Studio Code.

My head hurts.

Edit: Now I've tried jarsigner and zipalign and it still doesn't want to install.

**EDIT2: Issue goes away when I move .apk to internal storage. Is this a legit solution?**

Comment: Can you please tell us did you creat project using `creat-react-native init` or `react-native init` ?

Comment: `react-native init`

Comment: After EDIT2 : See the #3 and #4 on my list 4. Storage location 3. SD Card not mounted in the device. It MIGHT be your phone is connected to PC which can access the SD Card from your device. Then when you install an App and choose to save it to your SD Card, you will see Android App not installed error because the App cannot find the SD card as it is not mounted in your device.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended question and it's quite hard to give a clear answer without further information. But usually 'App not installed' error happens because of following reasons (among others)

1. Insufficient storage
2. Corrupted/Contaminated App file
3. SD Card not mounted in the device
4. Storage location
5. Corrupt storage
6. Application Permission
7. Incorrect file

**things you can try**

- Do the *tried and tested* "Have you turned it off and on again"?
- Delete unnecessary files/Apps
- Reset All the App Preference

  1. Go to Settings on your Android device.
  2. Open Apps or Apps manager.
  3. check for All Apps.
  4. Tap on the menu icon.
  5. Click on ‘Reset App Preferences’.
- Clear Data and Cache of Package Installer

  1. Open setting on your Android device.
  2. Look for the option called Apps or Manage apps and tap on it.
  3. Check for the Package Installer App under system Apps
  4. You will find two option of Clear data and Clear cache. (For Android Marshmallow 6.0 users check for option Storage to clear data and cache)
  5. Clear the data and cache to solve the problem.

You could also try changing the bundle id and see if that would do the trick

Hope this helped

Comment: I don't think devices are the problem, since it appears on all of them (more then 5)

Comment: Have you tried opening the `PROJ_ROOT/android/` folder in Android Studio and creating a signed APK. It should result in the same APK as the link you mentioned, but might be worth a try.

Comment: I tried it. Even ticked V1 and V2 versions that seem to solve everyone elses issue.